# How to connect to a websphere Application Server 8.5 Message Queue while Administrative Security is enabled

Tags: jms, websphere

i have written a little client test programm running against a **Websphere Applicationserver Message Topic**.
All works fine.
Now, if i am turning on the administrative security i got an error.

That's the code i am using.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try {
    /**
    * Lookup connection factory object using jndi
    */
    System.out.println("* Looking up CF in jndi...");
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://192.168.195.144:2809");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

    Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

    TopicConnectionFactory fact=(TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("jms/Ttestsecure");
    TopicConnection connect = fact.createTopicConnection();
    TopicSession session=connect.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Topic topic=null;
    try
    {
        topic =(Topic) ctx.lookup("jms/Totestsecure");
        System.out.println(topic.getTopicName());

    }
```

An here's the error i am getting

> Looking up CF in jndi...
>   JSAS1480I: Die Sicherheit ist nicht aktiviert, weil die ConfigURL-Eigenschaftendatei nicht definiert ist.
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
>       at testmsg.main(testmsg.java:31)
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1457)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1423)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1379)
>       at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
>       at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
>       at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:313)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:357)
>       at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
>       at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:97)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1983)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2008)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1186)
>       at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1272)
>       ... 17 more
>   I'am not very familiar with the websphere Server has anybody an advice what is going wrong ?
>   I have only turned on the administrative security note the bus security.
>   If i turn i off all works regular.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 3):

The exception you got indicates you did not set the ConfigURL for the client

> JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file
>   is not set.
>
> ```
> Explanation   The com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL property specified in setupCmdLine.bat or on the java command line is not set.
> Action    To enable security, set the com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL property to a properties file which exists, such as the sas.client.props file.
> ```

You are missing

```
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/sas.client.props
```

---

You can read the instructions on the Info Center: [Running the IBM Thin Client for Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got some problems with ssl config but know it works