# Unable to lookup if SSL is enabled in Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, ssl, ejb, websphere, websphere-8

I have written a simple ejb thin client to look up the bean deployed in IBM WebSphere 8.5.

When SSL was not enabled on the server I was successfully able to lookup the bean , but as soon as I enabled the SSL , I started getting the below mentioned exception.

This is how I enabled the security thru admin console :[image]

**Exception:**

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
at nh.indi.test.S2SCommTest.lookupServiceEJB(S2SCommTest.java:55)
at nh.indi.test.S2SCommTest.main(S2SCommTest.java:22) 
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
... 10 more
```

**Code :**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NamingException {

    Properties ejbProps = new Properties();
    ejbProps.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");
    ejbProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    ejbProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:160.XX.XX.XX:2809");

    InitialContext ffmContext = new InitialContext(ejbProps);
    Object remoteObject = ffmContext
            .lookup("ejb/MyAppEar-CLUSTER/MyAppEJB.jar/BatchIdTrackingBean#indi.nh.business.framework.bos.di.BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote");

    BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote serviceTester = (BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote) PortableRemoteObject
            .narrow(remoteObject, BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote.class);

    System.out.println(serviceTester);

}
```

While running the program I am also passing the sas.client.props file location present in my local file system as mentioned here. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtKGH.png)

```
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///C:/Temp/docs/S2S_Docs/sas.client.props
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtKGH.png) : [How to connect to a websphere Application Server 8.5 Message Queue while Administrative Security is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840637/how-to-connect-to-a-websphere-application-server-8-5-message-queue-while-adminis)

Can anybody please help me how to test it successfully with SSL enabled on the websphere app server or what i am missing in my client side or server side configuration.

Comment: In your SSL config you have currently set `Client certificate authentication` as required. Are you really want to do that? Since in that case you have to set mutual two way SSL. Put the WAS cert to client truststore and put the client cert to WAS trust store. If you jjust want just to enable SSL, set client cert to never, and make sure you have WAS cert in your client truststore.

Comment: After setting Client certificate authentication to never , that exception gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add this property to java command:  -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/sas.client.props

You can copy the ssl.client.props file (in addition to sas.client.props) from the WebSphere Application Server installation. You need to at least update the location of the key files in the ssl.client.props file to the match where you created or copied the key files. For example,

-Dcom.ibm.ssl.keyStore=/home/user1/etc/key.p12 
-Dcom.ibm.ssl.trustStore=/home/user1/etc/trust.p12

When you run the client again, it should prompt you to add signer to the trust store if it is not there.

More details at: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html

Comment: Thanks, - After making the changes as per Gas's comments and following your steps I am able to successfully lookup the bean with SSL-Required enabled.
Since this question is answered my next worry is to ensure that handshakes are using SSL protocol. I am planning to use wireshark to capture the network traffic. 
I will let you know if i see something different.