# SSL handshake not happening for RMI calls in Websphere

Tags: ssl, ejb, websphere, rmi, wireshark

As per my last question and with the help I was successfully able to look up an ejb deployed in websphere using the thin client.

[Unable to lookup if SSL is enabled in Websphere 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003351/unable-to-lookup-if-ssl-is-enabled-in-websphere-8-5)

I had also made the SSL-Required for both the inbound and outbound communication.

To conclude my testing I thought of capturing the traffic using the Wireshark to ensure that all the communication is happening over SSL instead of TCP/IP but to my surprise when I seen the packets in wireshark it is still using the TCP/IP and all the data was transferring in text format.

My understanding is once the "SSL-Required" is enabled at the transport layer all the communication and handshake should be happening over SSL rather than TCP/IP. Is my understanding correct ?

**Server Configuration :**

[image]

**Sample Client:**

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws NamingException {
    Properties ejbProps = new Properties();
    ejbProps.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");
    ejbProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    ejbProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:160.XX.XX.XX:2809");
    InitialContext ffmContext = new InitialContext(ejbProps);
    Object remoteObject = ffmContext
            .lookup("ejb/MyAppEar-CLUSTER/MyAppEJB.jar/BatchIdTrackingBean#indi.nh.business.framework.bos.di.BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote");
    BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote serviceTester = (BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote) PortableRemoteObject
        .narrow(remoteObject, BatchIdTrackingBeanRemote.class);
    System.out.println(serviceTester);
}
```

**Wireshark capture :**
[image]

Here , X.X.X.126 is my client location from where I am executing thin client and X.X.X.241 is my websphere app server where i am doing the lookup.

**Update :**
On analyzing more , i found that when I had enabled the "SSL-Required" , all the data is transferring over TCP/IP but it is encrypted , my understanding is it should be displayed as SSL instead of TCP in wireshark , isn't it ? . And when I made the transport type as only "TCP/IP" , then data transfers over GIOP and I can see the all the data in Text format.

Can anybody please confirm on this behavior ?

Comment: If it is set to SSL-Required and see encrypted data, then you are using ssl. Why wireshark display it as TCP, I dont know, maybe it only displays SSL for well known ports like 443 or https. You could try to access admin console `https://host:9043/ibm/console` and see what is displayed in wireshark then.

Comment: Didn't see SSL anywhere though I had seen SSH for some of the packets , I think that is the initial handhsake not sure though.